# How to accept/dismiss unhandled alerts with WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

How can I click accept/dismiss unhandledalerts with WebDriver?

Is it possible to check where the unhandled alerts are coming?

How can I use UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR capability? It is not working as I expected?

I've tried like this

```
DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, "Accept");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
WebDriver driver;
@BeforeClass
public void setUp() {

    DesiredCapabilities dc=new DesiredCapabilities();
    dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR,UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.ACCEPT);
    driver =new FirefoxDriver(dc);
}
```

I hope this would be helpful to you.

Comment: I expected like, If there is any unhandled alert present it should accept(click on OK).but,it is not happening.It is throwing UnhandledAlertException.

Comment: Are you catching that exception in ur catch block?

Answer (score 0):

Open Firefox and try 'about:config'.

Findout which Preference Name can solve you problem and set values accordingly using below code. example: I am disabling automatic update of Firefox.

```
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setPreference("app.update.enabled", false);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```